# Hide certain field on form alter using AJAX

Tags: 8, ajax, webforms

I have a webform created using interface, and need to hide some fields through button. Using form_alter I have added that button added AJAX call with it. Now I want to remove/hide certain element using that button and AJAX.

Below is the sample code

```
function xyz_user_signup_form_webform_submission_form1_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {


  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'xyz/xyz.global';

  $form['start'] = [
      '#type' => 'button',

      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => 'xyz_user_signup',
       ],
      '#value' => t('START >>'),
  ];

}

function xyz_user_signup(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $elements = &WebformFormHelper::flattenElements($form['elements']);


    $elements['field1']['#access'] = FALSE;


    return $elements;
}
```

On clicking start button I want to hide field1.

Comment: `Please share your inputs` how about sharing your alter code... otherwise we would have to be psychics.

Comment: Sure let me edit the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX needs to have a target ID where it will put your AJAX output. You declare that ID in the `wrapper` key.

**In your form_alter**

```
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => 'xyz_user_signup',
    'wrapper' => 'load-me-here-id', // This element is updated with this AJAX callback.
   ],
```

Then you need to wrap the field with this ID so AJAX replaces it.

```
 $form['elements']['field1']['#attributes'] = ['id' => 'load-me-here-id'];
```

**In your ajax callback**

```
return $elements['field1']; // so it doesn't return the entire form.
```

Comment: I implement as per your suggestion, but in ajax callback my code is to set #access property to FALSE of a fieldset element which is not working yet.

Comment: @parth.k Make sure your ajax is indeed working. For testing purposes, put `return 'Hello World';` you should see that "hello world", if not then AJAX it is still not working like it's suppose to.

Comment: @parth.k updated my answer, forgot to add elements to the attributes array.